# mysql to postgres CONVERT(0x4f6765 using utf8mb4)

Tags: postgresql, data-conversion

`Select CONVERT(0x4f6765 using utf8mb4);`

works well in mysql, what is the equivalent in postgres?
We have data in hexa, and need to convert it to VarChar, so using the above approach.

I tried CAST, but it doesn't work:
 `select CAST(0x4f6765 using utf8mb4)`

It throws error.

Comment: did you try using DECODE?

Comment: Read the docs [Binary string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html): *convert ( bytes bytea, src_encoding name, dest_encoding name ) → bytea*. Though `utf8mb4` is not in the Postgres [Character Conversions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CONVERSIONS-SUPPORTED).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT convert_from(decode('4F6765', 'hex'), 'UTF8');
```